# Why are my breakpoints hollow?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I am writing code in Visual Studio 2017, using C# for Unity.

Sometimes, when I add a breakpoint in some places, it is a hollow circle [image], opposed to the normal circle [image].  When this happens, the breakpoint doesn't hit.

If I try and place a breakpoint on an empty line or method signature, I get a hollow breakpoint.  But I will also get them on valid, debuggable lines of code.  I can debug the hollow ones by finding a valid breakpoint above it, and stepping down.

The breakpoints are not disabled:
[image]

Why are my breakpoints hollow sometimes?  What does it mean?  How can I stop it?

Comment: Did you hover over the hollow circle? What did it say?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann It doesn't have a tooltip.

Comment: Most likely the hollow ones are disabled. Right click on them and enable breakpoint

Comment: @phuzi not disabled.  See screen shot above

Comment: What screenshot?

Comment: @phuzi sorry about that. must have forgot to save edit.  added

Comment: Ah right you're on MacOS. The context menu is somewhat different on Windows. Wondered why the "normal circle" wasn't solid.

Comment: It is hollow as long as the DLL has not been loaded yet or the pdb file for the DLL could not be found.  Use Debug > Windows > Modules to chase it down.  If you see the DLL in the list then right-click it to get more info.  Oh, wait, whatever you'd do on an Apple machine to get a right-click :)  If you don't see it in the list then you need to make sure the relevant statement has executed that forces the DLL to be loaded.  Just-in-time.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks!  I believe right click on a Mac is Command-Shift-DoubleClick-Pirouette-K

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT unfortunately not.  I think I am going to chalk this up as one of the mysteries of mac

Comment: @HansPassant in Visual Studio for Mac Community Edition 8.2.5, there is no menu option for Debug, no menu option for Windows, and no menu option for Modules. And same thing in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I saw this message in the `Application Output` window:

```
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives(System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32)' to [0x0](no debug symbols).
```

note that at the end of the message it says `(no debug symbols)`. So just simply **Cleaning** and **Rebuilding** and also deleting `bin` and `obj` folders of all projects worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem... closed Visual Studio and reopened, back to normal now.